# event.preventDefault() not working for submit on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, submit, shortcode, preventdefault

I am writing wordpress plugin.
I have some form jQuery script and I need use `event.preventDefault();` (in a shortcode) for that. But `event.preventDefault();` is not working for submit button, but it´s working, for example, for a link.

Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

**In shortcode:**

```
echo '<a href="#" class="test" id="test_1">Some text</a>';
echo '<a href="#" class="test" id="test_2">Some text</a>';
echo '<a href="#" class="test" id="test_3">Some text</a>';  

echo '<form action=" " class="answerform" method="POST" >';

echo '<input  id=' . $answerid .' class=".submitform" type="submit"  value=' . $answer->answer . '>';
                    echo '</form>';
```

**Script:**

```
jQuery(function($){ 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".submitform" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    $( ".test" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've prepended your submit input element class with a `.` (ie - `class=".submitform"` when it should be `class="submitform"`)

It should be, simply:

```
echo '<input  id=' . $answerid .' class="submitform" type="submit"  value=' . $answer->answer . '>';
echo '</form>';
```

At the moment, your script is looking for an element with a class of `submitform`, which doesn't exist (your input element's class is currently `.submitform`).